# for some reason all my tabs are considered as one. how can i get them to be separate?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so id like for Home-Popular to each be able to be selected individually. Im not sure why its doing this so if you could leave a explanation that would also be appreciated. any help is appreciated along with tips to optimize future code. thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="script.js"defer></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cults.css">
<title> follow the cult </title>
</head>
    <h1 style="text-align:center"> CULT </h1> 
<body> 
<ul class="tabs">
    <li data-tab-target="#Home" class="active tab"> Home </li>
    <li data-tab-target="#Men" class="tab"> Men </li>
    <li data-tab-target="#Women" class="tab"> Women </li>
    <li data-tab-target="#New Arrivals" class="tab"> New Arrivals </li>
    <li data-tab-target="#Popular" class="tab"> Popular </li>
</ul> 
<br></br>
    <div class="tab-content">
       <div id="Home" data-tab-content class="active">
            <h1>home</h1>
            <p> Welcome Home</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Men"data-tab-content>
            <h1>Men</h1>
            <p> yang</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Women" data-tab-content>
            <h1>Women</h1>
            <p> ying</p>
        </div>
        <div id="New Arrivals"data-tab-content>
            <h1>New</h1>
            <p> new shit</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Popular"data-tab-content>
            <h1>The Orbit</h1>
            <p> most popular</p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

'css doc'

```
[data-tab-content] {
display: none;
}

.active[data-tab-content] {
display: block;
}
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.tabs{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
.tab {
    cursor :pointer;
    padding: 10px;
}
.tabs.active {
    background-color:#CCC;
}
.tabs:hover{
    background-color:#AAA;
}
.tab-content {
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

'script'

```
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-target]')
const tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-content]')

tabs.forEach(tab => {
    tab.addEventListener('click',() => {
        const target = document.querySelector(tab.dataset.tabTarget )
        tabContents.forEach(tabContent => {
         tabContent.classlist.remove'active'))
        })
        tab.forEach(tab => {
         tab.classlist.remove'active'))
        })
        tab.classList.add('active')
         target.classlist.add('active')
    })
})
```

any help is appreciated along with tips to optimize future code. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You targeted the parent element instead of individual tabs in your CSS, that's why the `:hover` was highlighting all the tabs.
2. `#New Arrivals`. spaces have meanings when using `querySelector`, you are selecting nested element. `element under **Arrivals** also the child of **#new**`, omit the space.
3. use `event.target` to refer to the tab you click on.

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-target]')
const tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-content]')
tabs.forEach(tab => {
    tab.addEventListener('click',(event) => {
        const target = document.querySelector(event.target.dataset.tabTarget)
        tabs.forEach(tab => {
         tab.classList.remove('active')
        })
        event.target.classList.add('active');

        tabContents.forEach(tabContent => {
         tabContent.classList.remove('active')
        })
        target.classList.add('active')
    })
})
```

```css
[data-tab-content] {
display: none;
}

.active[data-tab-content] {
display: block;
}
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.tabs{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
.tab {
    cursor :pointer;
    padding: 10px;
}
.tab.active {
    background-color:#CCC;
}
.tab:hover{
    background-color:#AAA;
}
.tab-content {
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="script.js"defer></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cults.css">
<title> follow the cult </title>
</head>
    <h1 style="text-align:center"> CULT </h1> 
<body> 
<ul class="tabs">
    <li data-tab-target="#Home" class="active tab"> Home </li>
    <li data-tab-target="#Men" class="tab"> Men </li>
    <li data-tab-target="#Women" class="tab"> Women </li>
    <li data-tab-target="#NewArrivals" class="tab"> New Arrivals </li>
    <li data-tab-target="#Popular" class="tab"> Popular </li>
</ul> 
<br></br>
    <div class="tab-content">
       <div id="Home" data-tab-content class="active">
            <h1>home</h1>
            <p> Welcome Home</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Men"data-tab-content>
            <h1>Men</h1>
            <p> yang</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Women" data-tab-content>
            <h1>Women</h1>
            <p> ying</p>
        </div>
        <div id="NewArrivals" data-tab-content>
            <h1>New</h1>
            <p> new shit</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Popular" data-tab-content>
            <h1>The Orbit</h1>
            <p> most popular</p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: after trying to add the code, and even copying it, only the home page [tab-contents ] are displayed, im still meddling around with it but any ideas to what the problem is

Comment: any errors in the console? Also, try it on a different browser.